# yocto d.getVar fails

Tags: yocto, bitbake

Learning Yocto from http://book.yoctoprojectbook.com/index. Chapter 4 has the following code

```
SUMMARY = "Recipe to build the 'nano' editor"

PN = "nano"
PV = "2.2.6"

SITE = "http://www.nano-editor.org/dist"
PV_MAJOR = "${@bb.data.getVar('PV', d, 1).split('.')[0]}"
PV_MINOR = "${@bb.data.getVar('PV', d, 1).split('.')[1]}"

SRC_URI = "${SITE}/v${PV_MAJOR}.${PV_MINOR}/${PN}-${PV}.tar.gz"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "03233ae480689a008eb98feb1b599807"
SRC_URI[sha256sum] = \
"be68e133b5e81df41873d32c517b3e5950770c00fc5f4dd23810cd635abce67a"

python do_fetch() {
    bb.plain("Downloading source tarball from ${SRC_URI} ...")
    src_uri = (d.getVar('SRC_URI', True) or "").split()
    if 0 == len(src_uri):
        bb.fatal('Empty URI')
    try:
        fetcher = bb.fetch2.Fetch(src_uri, d)
        fetcher.download()
    except bb.fetch2.BBFetchException:
        bb.fatal('Could not fetch source tarball.')
    bb.plain("Download successful.")
}

addtask fetch before do_build

python do_unpack() {
    bb.plain("Unpacking source tarball ...")
    os.system("tar x -C ${WORKDIR} -f ${DL_DIR}/${P}.tar.gz")
    bb.plain("Unpacked source tarball.")
}

addtask unpack before do_build after do_fetch

python do_configure() {
    bb.plain("Configuring source package ...")
    os.system("cd ${WORKDIR}/${P} && ./configure")
    bb.plain("Configured source package.")
}

addtask configure before do_build after do_unpack

python do_compile() {
    bb.plain("Compiling package ...")
    os.system("cd ${WORKDIR}/${P} && make")
    bb.plain("Compiled package.")
}

addtask compile before do_build after do_configure

do_clean[nostamp] = "1"
do_clean() {
    rm -rf ${WORKDIR}/${P}
    rm -f ${TMPDIR}/stamps/*
}

addtask clean
```

The recipe is located in meta-hello/recipes-editor/nano. Basically it is trying to build a `nano` text editor package. It is failing at the `do_fetch()` task. After some print statement debugging I figured out that the failure happens at this line: `src_uri = (d.getVar('SRC_URI', True) or "").split()`, specifically at `d.getVar('SRC_URI', True)`. I'm not really sure what exactly is causing the problem. Would anyone care to help? I'm running a `rocko` build of `yocto`.

Here is the terminal output I get when I run the recipe:

```
$bitbake nano
NOTE: Not using a cache. Set CACHE = <directory> to enable.
Parsing recipes: 100% |#################################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
Parsing of 2 .bb files complete (0 cached, 2 parsed). 2 targets, 0 skipped, 0 masked, 0 errors.
NOTE: Resolving any missing task queue dependencies
Initialising tasks: 100% |##############################################################################################################| Time: 0:00:00
NOTE: Executing RunQueue Tasks
Downloading source tarball from ${SRC_URI} ...
ERROR: nano-2.2.6-r0 do_fetch: Function failed: do_fetch
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/some-user/projects/bbhello/tmp/work/nano-2.2.6-r0/temp/log.do_fetch.14350
ERROR: Task (/home/some-user/projects/bbhello/meta-hello/recipes-editor/nano/nano.bb:do_fetch) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1 tasks of which 0 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/some-user/projects/bbhello/meta-hello/recipes-editor/nano/nano.bb:do_fetch
Summary: There was 1 ERROR message shown, returning a non-zero exit code.
```

And here is the actual log file:

```
DEBUG: Executing python function do_fetch
Downloading source tarball from ${SRC_URI} ...
DEBUG: Python function do_fetch finished
ERROR: Function failed: do_fetch
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're testing but if I try this example it fails during parsing with:

> ERROR: ExpansionError during parsing
>   /media/build/poky/meta/recipes-core/base-files/test_1.0.bb
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/media/build/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/data_smart.py", line 412, in
>   DataSmart.expandWithRefs(s='${SITE}/v${PV_MAJOR}.${PV_MINOR}/${PN}-${PV}.tar.gz',
>   varname='SRC_URI'):
>                    try:
>       >                s = **expand_var_regexp**.sub(varparse.var_sub, s)
>                        try:   File "/media/build/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/data_smart.py", line 111, in
>   VariableParse.var_sub(match=<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(9, 20),
>   match='${PV_MAJOR}'>):
>                    else:
>       >                var = self.d.getVarFlag(key, "_content")
>                    self.references.add(key)   File "/media/build/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/data_smart.py", line 794, in
>   DataSmart.getVarFlag(var='PV_MAJOR', flag='_content', expand=True,
>   noweakdefault=False, parsing=False):
>                        cachename = var + "[" + flag + "]"
>       >            value = self.expand(value, cachename)
>           File "/media/build/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/data_smart.py", line 436, in DataSmart.expand(s="${@bb.data.getVar('PV', d,
>   1).split('.')[0]}", varname='PV_MAJOR'):
>            def expand(self, s, varname = None):
>       >        return self.expandWithRefs(s, varname).value
>           File "/media/build/poky/bitbake/lib/bb/data_smart.py", line 426, in DataSmart.expandWithRefs(s="${@bb.data.getVar('PV', d,
>   1).split('.')[0]}", varname='PV_MAJOR'):
>                    except Exception as exc:
>       >                raise ExpansionError(varname, s, exc) from exc
>         bb.data_smart.ExpansionError: Failure expanding variable PV_MAJOR, expression was ${@bb.data.getVar('PV', d, 1).split('.')[0]}
>   which triggered exception AttributeError: module 'bb.data' has no
>   attribute 'getVar'

which is because the bb.data.getVar('PV', d, 1) needs to be d.getVar('PV', True). This recipe as stated cannot parse under rocko so I don't think you're running the recipe you think you are?

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I wasn't testing anything. Just learning Yocto and this is the code that is provided in the book.